# Python - How to import module from .so file from egg file without using an absolute file path

Tags: python, import, extending, pkg-resources

I built the [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/) library with `python setup.py bdist_egg` command and uploaded it onto Spark for my PySpark job.

However, the .so file inside pyahocorasick can't be imported through `pkg_resources.resource_filename()` method on Spark cluster for security reasons.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark_datawash.py", line 251, in <module>
    import ahocorasick
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ahocorasick.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ahocorasick.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1152, in resource_filename
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1696, in get_resource_filename
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1726, in _extract_resource
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1219, in get_cache_path
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1199, in extraction_error
pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /home/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

This is how pyahocorasick import the .so:

```
def __bootstrap__():
    global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
    import sys, pkg_resources, imp 
    __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'ahocorasick.so')
    __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

Can I import the .so by `resource_stream()` instead of `resource_filename()` or some other way without the need to read from an absolute file path? 
Thanks all.

BTW, I can't install pyahocorasick on every node on Spark cluster for other reasons. So I have to upload an egg-zipped distribution for later use.